# Django - Datatables with Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-datatable

I am using this [library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-datatables) for **datatables** in **django-rest**. Everything is working fine expect **request.user session** in views. It seems to me **django-datatable** is not authenticating the user token and therefore request.user returns anonymous user. And the same is accessible even without sending user token in headers.

Here is my code :

```
class MyDataTableView(BaseDatatableView):
    """
    """
    model = MyModel
    columns = [***columns** ]
    order_columns = [***columns**]

    def get_initial_queryset(self):
        """
        initial queryset for 
        """
        self.request.user -----> returns antonymous user 

        queryset = self.model.objects
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 1):

Have You tried to subclass `BaseDatatableView` and overwrite its .get like:

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().get(*args, **kwargs)
    print(self.request)
```

My guess is that `get_initial_queryset` can be invoked before actual request dispatch, so the user is anonymous there. When You look into the code of `django_datatables/mixins.py`, there is a mixin called `JsonResponseMixin`. It's GET method is directly responsible for request processing, so You should look for Your answers there. The easiest way - subclass it and overwrite the method.

Comment: No , I haven't overwrite get , but surely will look at this

Comment: Are You sending the token with the request?

Comment: Have You tried to check if `Authentication` header is present in the request?
You can check it like
`"Authentication" in self.request`

Comment: sorry for late reply , I checked for the Authentication header and its not there in request but I am sending the Authentication header like for other requests -> 
    `response = requests.get(api, headers={'Authorization': token_header}, params=request.GET.dict(), verify=True)`
.

Comment: also token_header is present here `self.request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the token JS to the Datatables initiation JS file?  django-datatables just creates the correct JSON string.  Initiating the cookie is different.

I fought with this a while and my missing piece was that I had to get and set the cookie:

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

this is above where I set the Datatables params for example :

```
let table = $('#datatables').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
     stateSave: true,
    "ajax": {
```

........